# When all AJAX requests complete

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an ajax request that grabs some data and then splits it up into an array.  The array length is variable.

```
  var ajax1 = $.ajax({
    url: 'myurl.php',
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function (data) {

      //create an array

    }

  });
```

Once I have the array, I want to loop through it and in each iteration run another AJAX request.  I put it inside a $.when to make sure the initial ajax request was complete:

```
  $.when(ajax1).done(
    function() {

      for (i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {

        $.ajax({
          url: 'anotherurl?=' + myarray[i],
          type: "GET",
          dataType: "jsonp",
          success: function (data) {

            //do stuff here

          }
        });

      }

    }
  )
```

My question is, how can I get a message box to pop up when the for loop has completed all the AJAX requests? A simple `alert('complete')` at the end of the loop won't work as the AJAX is done async.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to wait until jQuery ajax request finishes in a loop?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20291366/how-to-wait-until-jquery-ajax-request-finishes-in-a-loop)

Comment: a better solution will be to do a maximum of 2 ajax calls

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this by also using `$.when`. You just need to store all the AJAX requests you make in an array and `apply()` that array to `$.when`. Try this:

```
$.when(ajax1).done(function() {
    var requests = [];
    for (i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {
        requests.push($.ajax({
            url: 'anotherurl?=' + myarray[i],
            dataType: "JSONP",
            success: function (data) {
                // do stuff here
            }
        }));
    }
    $.when.apply($, requests).done(function() {
        console.log('complete');
    });
})
```

You can also shorten the logic slightly by using `map()`, although be aware this won't work in < IE9.

```
$.when(ajax1).done(function() {
    var requests = array.map(function() {
        return $.ajax({
            url: 'anotherurl?=' + myarray[i],
            dataType: "JSONP",
            success: function (data) {
                // do stuff here
            }
        });
    });
    $.when.apply($, requests).done(function() {
        console.log('complete');
    });
})
```

Answer (score 9):

As of JQuery 1.5, `$.ajax()` return an object which implement the promise interface, so you can store all of those promises in an array and wait for them to finish using `Promise.all()`.

Something like:

```
  var root = 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com';
  var p = [];

  p.push( $.ajax({url: root + '/posts/1', method: 'GET'}));
  p.push( $.ajax({url: root + '/posts/2', method: 'GET'}));
  p.push( $.ajax({url: root + '/posts/3', method: 'GET'}));
  p.push( $.ajax({url: root + '/posts/4', method: 'GET'}));

  Promise.all(p).then(values => { 
    console.log( 'Ajax responses after they have all finished: ', values); 
  });
```

See this [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZGT32NcyShnhi0VVuWvj?p=preview) for an exemple.

Hope this help !

Comment: Good use of Promise.all. With an array of URLs, you can do somethings like that: const loadUrls = async urls => {  
  let results = [];
  urls.forEach(url => {
    results.push($.ajax({url}));        
  })    
  return await Promise.all(results);  
}

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is going to rear its stubborn head pretty quickly here. I'd recommend you reach for something better like Promises that give you more control in this type of situation

```
const pajax = opts=>
  new Promise((resolve, reject)=>
    $.ajax(opts).done(x => resolve(x)).fail((_,_,err)=> reject(err))
```

Then you could use it like this with [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

```
pajax({
  url: 'myurl.php',
  type: "GET",
  dataType: "jsonp",
})
.then(data => {
  // create your arr
  let arr = ...

  return Promise.all(arr.map(x=> {
    return pajax({
     url: 'anotherurl?=' + x,
     type: "GET",
     dataType: "jsonp"
    })
  }))
})
.then(data => {
  console.log('this is called after all promises are done'
})
.catch(err=> {
  console.error(err)
})
```

EDIT

@RoryMcCrossan's answer is nice if you want to keep everything in the jQuery realm