# how to merge response array run multiple ajax calls before resolving a promise

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

I have ajax nested in the loop. Now I want to merge the ajax returned into an array or a single object. Thanks!

```
$.each(res.data, function (key, value) {
    SerialNumber = value['serial'];
    Code = value['code_history'][0]['gift_code'];
    return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: "Code=" + Code + "&action=cameraInfo_more" + "&SerialNumber=" + SerialNumber,
            url: "ajax/get-customer-info-params",
            cache: false,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (res_more) {
                temp2 = res_more.data[0];

                //-- i want merge all json res_more to 1 array

                }
           })
        })
    })
}
```

Comment: Have you try with concat? . Before each loop declare empty array .
let temp2 = []  and in success function . temp2.concat(res_more.data[0]);

Comment: You can push your ajax call in array and then use promise.all, to resolve it. Can you please refer answers in this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38738614/when-all-ajax-requests-complete

Answer (score 1):

You're using $.each, but if you used `Array.prototype.map` you would end up with an array of promises. Feed that to `Promise.all` and wait for it to return.

Here's an example:

```
Promise.all(res.data.map(value => {
    SerialNumber = value['serial'];
    Code = value['code_history'][0]['gift_code'];
    return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: "Code=" + Code + "&action=cameraInfo_more" + "&SerialNumber=" + SerialNumber,
            url: "ajax/get-customer-info-params",
            cache: false,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (res_more) {
                resolve(res_more.data[0]);

            }
        })
    })
})).then(x => {
    console.log(x);
});
```

Comment: can you help me for example?

Comment: Sure, here you go :)