# jQuery - for cycle ajax calls

Tags: jquery, ajax

I need to make ajax calls in a cycle making new call after the previous is finished.

```
for (var year = 2000; year <= 2017; year++) 
{ 
    $.ajax(
    {
        url: 'calendar.php?year=' + year,
        beforeSend: function()
        {
            console.log('Loading year: ' + year);
        },
        success: function(result)
        {
            $('#events').append(result);
        }
    });
}
```

But when I check the console all calls are made at the same time.

Comment: That's because the `for` loop executes in a couple of milliseconds. If you want to delay the calls, use `setInterval()` or chained `setTimeout()` calls - although I'd suggest if possible making a single request to get data for all relevant years. Making 17 rapid AJAX requests to your server * the number of concurrent users you have isn't a great idea

Answer (score 2):

You could use the Promise API of jQuery to chain up the requests.
Whenever on request is finished the `queryYears` is called another time with the `year` incremented by one, until `year` is larger then `maxYear`

```
function queryYears(year, maxYear) {
  // check if the year is less or equal maxYear
  if (year <= maxYear) {
    return $.ajax({
        url: 'calendar.php?year=' + year,
        beforeSend: function() {
          console.log('Loading year: ' + year);
        }
      })
      .then(function(result) {
        $('#events').append(result);

        //incremenat year by one
        year++;

        //only call queryYears if year is less or equal to maxYear
        if (year <= maxYear) {
          return queryYears(year, maxYear);
        }
      })
  } else {
    // if not return a rejected Promise
    return Promise.reject(new Error(year + ' is larger then ' + mxYear))
  }
}



queryYears(2000, 2017)
.then(function() {
  console.log('finished')
})
.catch(function(err) {
   console.log('failed with: ')
   console.dir(err)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A nasty way to do it could be to set your `$ajax` option `async` to false, however, this is not recommended, it can back up the browser and give the users a bad experience. Instead you could create an array of promises. This could help [How to wait until jQuery ajax request finishes in a loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20291366/how-to-wait-until-jquery-ajax-request-finishes-in-a-loop)