# I have 2 functions in my Javascript.One has multiple ajax calls to get the data and other displays the data.The functions are not executed in sequence

Tags: ajax

```
Sample Code

$( document ).ready(function() {
    getData();
    LoadData();
});

function getData() {
        alert('getData');
        Data='';
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "http://localhost:34126/SAL/FCDataService.svc/GetMonthlyInvValue",
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: {},
            processdata: true,
            async: false,
            success: function (json) {
                Data= json;
               alert('Data:' + Data);
            },
            error: function (e) {
                alert('error ' + e.status + '  ' + e.responseText);
            }
        });

}

function LoadData() {
        alert('LoadData');

    }
```

The expected Output:
getData
Data:{"label": "Jan", "Value": "1"}
LoadData

The actual Output :
getData
LoadData
Data:{"label": "Jan", "Value": "1"}

What am I doing wrong.Please help me!!

Comment: Yes, I have shown only one ajax call here, but my code there are multiple. I have want to call Loaddata() function after all the ajax calls are done.

Comment: Do do synchronous ajax calls -- instead look at how to do promise for each ajax call, and create a promise array and run your loadData function when all the promises resolves

Comment: @Soren, It would be helpful if you could show me an example for this.

Comment: @CrazyCoder - There are plenty of example already without I have to write one, this was on the first result page I found in a search: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44691096/668501

Comment: @Soren, Thanks a lot. It solved my problem  :)

Answer (score 1):

why don't  you call `LoadData()` after success?
like below

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    getData();

});

function getData() {
        alert('getData');
        Data='';
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "http://localhost:34126/SAL/FCDataService.svc/GetMonthlyInvValue",
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: {},
            processdata: true,
            async: false,
            success: function (json) {
                data= json;
               alert('Data:' + data);
                LoadData();
            },
            error: function (e) {
                alert('error ' + e.status + '  ' + e.responseText);
            }
        });

}

function LoadData() {
        alert('LoadData');

    }
```

### UPDATE :

as you said , you are having multiple ajax calls,

one work around could be ,

try setting flag for each ajax call and make them true on respective success event , and lastly you need to call `loadData()` from all success completion and in `loadData(){ ...}` body check all the  success are completed or not,

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    getData();
     $flag1= flase;
     $flag2= flase;
     $flag3= flase;
     $flag4= flase;


});


  function LoadData() {
         if($flag1 && $flag2 && $flag3 && $flag4)
             {
                   alert('LoadData');
             }    
       }
```

and in each ajax call's success

```
         success: function (json) {
            data= json;
           alert('Data:' + data);
           $flag1=true;
            LoadData();
        },
```

and don't forget to make all flag false in `$(document).ready(){}`

Comment: In my actual code, there are multiple ajax calls which gets different json objects. Load charts uses these jsons together and does some calculations. So I cannot call  LoadData() each time.

Comment: @CrazyCoder check my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Inside success function call the LoadData() function

```
success: function (json) {
    Data= json;
    alert('Data:' + stackMonthData);
    LoadData();
},
```

Comment: I cannot. Because in getData(), there are multiple ajax calls. In sample I have given only one call.But in my actual code there are multiple calls to get different data.And LoadData() function uses all these data.

Answer (score -1):

AJAX is asynchronous process ans ajax request start in different thread, so JavaScript not wait for AJAX response, so there is two possible way to handle it

1. Make AJAX request in synchronous process, by pass `async:false` in jquery AJAX parameter
2. call getData() function in AJAX callback liks success/error or done/faild callback something like

   $.ajax({
     // your code
   }).done(function(data) {
      getData() 
   }).fail(function(data){
   });